# How to modify JS file generated by webpack?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, webpack

I am working on a child theme of GeneratePress. I am new with GeneratePress.
In a child theme, there are multiple Gutenberg (GeneratePress) Blocks created by previous developer.

Now, I need to modify one Blocks to meet the requirement.

The question is how I can modify the JS files generated by webpack as per NPM flow?

I have done analysis and try to find the location of the code/content based on requirement.
After searching the code, I am landed on a JS file which is generated by webpack

I don't have any folder in a theme which has files associated with **webpack / package.json** / or so.

[See JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWoFL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think should modify it just modify your normall css files and "npm run dev"

Comment: I need to modify the JavaScript that is generated(build) using webpack